# Supporting multi login for same account using tokens

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, token

The normal token based authentication works as follows

1. The client sends a username and a password to the server.
2. The server will add that client as a first time user and generate a token for the client and pass that token back to the client as a response.
3. The next time when the client wants to connect to the server, it will pass its uid and this token. The server will now verify the user using this token.

Now consider a scenario where we can have multiple devices from which multiple users might want to login into the same account. (These are valid users and not intruders. So this is a valid use case). As far as tokens is concerned, after reading up on this a bit I found that we need to have separate tokens for every user so that revoking one does not affect any of the other users.

My question however is that since **I need to uniquely identify a device and associate that device with the account**, what should be used as a unique device ID. Should we play on the **IMEI number** of the device or is that an anti pattern. What other possibilities are there for this use case.?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options available, but there is no 100% guarantee that they will always work. See the android developer blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Best method mentioned is Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID

Comment: I read that article but just wanted to know if this is a the best way to handle things in this scenario or not. What other options do I have apart from this ?

Comment: why not try logging the user with his user name and password.. so you can make multiple logins at the same time

Comment: First time login will involve a username and a password but telling the user to enter them every time is not secure. Token adds a layer of security.

Comment: Then you can try generating some random tokens for the same account if the user accepts it..

Comment: When the same account is tried to be logged in from different phone if the user accepts the registering then you can generate a seperate id then..